# Some Qt apps (dropbox, megasync) stopped working

Tags: 18.04, qt, libraries, dropbox, pyqt

Just recently some of the apps I had to backup files stopped working and I do not know why. For example, at trying to start `nautilus-dropbox` or `megasync` I get errors related to the Qt library. See the logs below.

Dropbox

```
sudo dropbox start
[sudo] password for b-fg: 
Starting Dropbox...dropbox: locating interpreter
dropbox: logging to /tmp/dropbox-antifreeze-gsXuyT
dropbox: initializing
dropbox: initializing python 3.5.4
dropbox: setting program path '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/dropbox'
dropbox: setting home path '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90'
dropbox: setting python path '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90:/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/python-packages-35.zip'
dropbox: python initialized
dropbox: running dropbox
dropbox: setting args
dropbox: applying overrides
dropbox: running main script
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/psutil._psutil_linux.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/psutil._psutil_posix.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/linuxffi.pthread._linuxffi_pthread.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/linuxffi.fcntl._linuxffi_fcntl.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/linuxffi.sys.compiled._linuxffi_sys.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/tornado.speedups.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/cpuid.compiled._cpuid.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/linuxffi.resolv.compiled._linuxffi_resolv.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/posixffi.libc._posixffi_libc.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/librsyncffi.compiled._librsyncffi.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/PyQt5.QtWebKit.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Dropbox isn't running!
Done!
b-fg@IHPC:~$ dropbox: load fq extension '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/PyQt5.QtWebKit.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
bn.BUILD_KEY: Dropbox
bn.VERSION: 54.4.90
bn.DROPBOXEXT_VERSION: failed
bn.is_frozen: True
machine_id: failed
pid: 9754
ppid: 1289
ppid exe: '/lib/systemd/systemd'
uid: 0
user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='root', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=0, pw_gid=0, pw_gecos='root', pw_dir='/root', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
effective_user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='root', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=0, pw_gid=0, pw_gecos='root', pw_dir='/root', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
euid: 0
gid: 0
egid: 0
group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='root', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=0, gr_mem=[])
effective_group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='root', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=0, gr_mem=[])
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: None
cwd: '/home/b-fg'
     real_path='/home/b-fg'
            mode=0o40755    uid=1000    gid=1000
     parent mode=0o40755    uid=0   gid=0
HOME: '/home/b-fg'
appdata: '/home/b-fg/.dropbox/instance1'
         real_path='/home/b-fg/.dropbox/instance1'
                mode=0o40700    uid=1000    gid=1000
         parent mode=0o40700    uid=1000    gid=1000
dropbox_path: '/home/b-fg/Dropbox'
              real_path='/home/b-fg/Dropbox'
                        mode=0o40700    uid=1000    gid=1000
              parent    mode=0o40755    uid=1000    gid=1000
sys_executable: '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/dropbox'
                real_path='/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/dropbox'
                        mode=0o100755   uid=1000    gid=1000
                parent  mode=0o40755    uid=1000    gid=1000
trace.__file__: '/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/python-packages-35.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                real_path='/home/b-fg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/python-packages-35.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                        not found
                parent  not found
tempdir: '/tmp'
         real_path='/tmp'
                mode=0o41777    uid=0   gid=0
         parent mode=0o40755    uid=0   gid=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 6689, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 3035, in run
  File "ui/common/uikit.pyc", line 744, in create_ui_kit
  File "dropbox/client/ui/qt/__init__.pyc", line 34, in <module>
  File "<_bootstrap_overrides>", line 162, in load_module
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1: symbol xmlBufContent version LIBXML2_2.9.0 not defined in file libxml2.so.2 with link time reference

Couldn't start Dropbox.
This is usually because of a permissions error. Storing your home folder on a network share can also cause an error.

Get more help at https://www.dropbox.com/c/help/permissions_error

Please check the system console for more details.
```

Megasync

```
sudo megasync
megasync: relocation error: megasync: symbol _ZN10QSslSocket13setPrivateKeyERK7QSslKey version Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Network.so.5 with link time reference
```

I have search this issue and tried some fixed such as including the following  lines in `~/.bashrc` with no luck

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I think there's a conflict with Qt versions and dependencies but I cannot figure out what exactly. Re-install the apps or rebooting didn't help either.

Comment: Why are you trying to run all these applications with `sudo`? What are your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Comment: `sudo` to make sure it is not a permissions error. It does not make a difference anyways. Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome.

Comment: I know 'me too' posts are frowned on but I too have noticed this from only yesterday using 16.04. The odd thing is, the dropbox icon on the top bar is greyed out but dropbox is still running and if you right click on it, it gives you all the options including the ability to launch the dropbox website after which, the icon is not greyed out for a short while then greyes out again. Files still seem to be correctly synced though despite the icon being greyed out.